# Is there a "pure R" implementation for loess? (with no C code?)

Tags: r, loess

I would like to manipulate the work done by the loess function in R.  However, the main workhorse of this function is written in C.  Is there some pure R implementation of the code?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it... LOESS is built-in in most statistical programs, thus there is no practical need to do that. what precisely do you want to alter inside?

Comment: For one thing, I would like to be able to get the parameters of the function for a particular point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loess.demo function in the TeachingDemos package replicates some of the internals in plain R (it also uses the built in C code version).  You could use that function as a starting place depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Greg, if I understand my poking, it seems that you are using the base loess to fit the original line, but then create an estimate per point according to the user's action (clicking) on the plot.  It will need some tweaking, but it is a good starting point - thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right, so you could take the per point part and build on that.  You will also want to ask yourself if you want the pure loess (the more wiggly line) or the spline smoothed version.